# Getting Kendo Grid Name in an Event Handler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to pass gridName to the Kendo event handler. `.Events(events => events.RequestEnd("requestEndEvent")`.

I am using Kendo UI version 2014.2.716.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently I updated Kendo UI and `e.sender.options.table.context.id` stopped working. I contacted Kendo and here is their response. The following method can be used to pass gridname to any event handler including error handler.

"You are relying on something that is not documented and is not supported. The correct way of passing Grid id to DataSource event handler is as follows:"

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
        .Events(e => e.RequestStart("requestStartHandler(\"grid\")"))
     )

<script>
    function requestStartHandler(gridName) {
        return function (e) {
            var grid = $("#" + gridName).data("kendoGrid");
            alert("Request Start for grid: " + gridName + ", items length: " + grid.items().length);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Only this worked for me : e.sender.content.context.id

Comment: @Misi don't forget to change `grid` in `requestStartHandler(\"grid\")` to what your grid's name is

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for anyone finding this now, the sending grid's id is accessible with e.sender.element[0].id

In previous versions e.sender.element.context.id would also work, but in latest versions (2018+) .context is undefined now. Element is still there, so .element[0].id should continue to work.

```
function requestEndEvent(e) {
    alert(e.sender.element[0].id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    function GridRequestEnd(e) {
        var gridName = null;
        $(".k-grid").each(function () {
            var currentGrid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
            if (currentGrid != null && currentGrid.dataSource == e.sender) {
                gridName = currentGrid.element.context.id;
            }
        });

        alert(gridName);  
 }
```